# Unable to generate jar of openwms and deploy

Tags: java, spring-boot, installation

I m trying to deploy org.openwms in my system but deployment is getting failed 
getting error.

'https://github.com/openwms/org.openwms'

getting an error:

```
mvn clean deploy -Prelease,gpg
```

**Update**

```
getting error [INFO] 
BUILD FAILURE [INFO] 
------------------------------------------------------------------------ [INFO]
Total time: 18.446 s [INFO] 
Finished at: 2019-07-23T13:06:06+05:30 [INFO] 
------------------------------------------------------------------------ [ERROR] 
Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:
maven-gpg-plugin:1.6:sign (sign-artifacts) on project org.openwms.services: 
Unable to execute gpg command: Error while executing process. 
Cannot run program "gpg.exe": 
CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified ->
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Was able to generate the jar file for the openwms (repo url in question) using the normal maven command.

```
mvn clean package
```

Regarding the error reported for `deploy` command, its configuration is missing in the pom file. Please refer the below command on how to setup the deploy goal for your project.

https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-deploy-plugin/

Comment: ohh. now i got it.